# Error while updating inMySQL

Tags: mysql, updates, sql-delete

I am working with MySQL and I am facing issues while updating the below command:

> UPDATE group_access_mst SET
>   access='0',view='0',add='0',modify='0',delete='0',save='0',xl='0',import='0' WHERE role_id='1' AND page_id='1';

ERROR:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'add='0',modify='0',delete='0',save='0',xl='0',import='0' WHERE
>   role_id='1' AND p' at line 1

If I remove add,delete from the quesry it works fine!!

Is there any way i can make these command to work. I can understand that in MySQL `ADD,DELETE,SELECT,INSERT` are commands so it is not working.

In this case i need to change the fields names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose the field names within back quote:

```
UPDATE group_access_mst
   SET `access`='0',
       `view`='0',
       `add`='0',
       `modify`='0', 
       `delete`='0',
       `save`='0',
       `xl`='0',
       `import`='0'
 WHERE role_id='1'
   AND page_id='1';
```